# Can I limit set dynamic ISpatialAudioClient objects to static values?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to solve a problem with the game Grand Theft Auto 5 (and perhaps other games) in how it interacts with Dolby Access virtual spatial sound. The problem is that when GTA 5 is launched, it is setting the spatial sound format to Off.
The spatial sound format can only be changed in two ways:

1. manually by the user in Windows settings, or
2. by the ISpatialAudioClient::GetMaxDynamicObjectCount function
   for dynamic objects returned by an application (resulting in 0 for
   GTA 5 in this case).

So essentially, I need help *forcing* Windows into always treating the "dynamic objects" as always having a static value returned on call.

I am a beginner with C++, trying to make a Console App. The code is as follows:

```
#include <spatialaudioclient.h>

int main() {
    HRESULT ActivateSpatialAudioObject(
        AudioObjectType         AudioObjectType_AudioObjectType_Dynamic,
        ISpatialAudioObject     **audioObject
    );
    HRESULT GetMaxDynamicObjectCount(
        UINT32 * 1
    );
    HRESULT OnAvailableDynamicObjectCountChange(
        ISpatialAudioObjectRenderStreamBase * sender,
        LONGLONG                            0,
        UINT32                              1
    );
}
```

Am I on the right track?

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/spatial-sound)